# recommended way of programming in my case?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, html, appmobi

So I want to develop something fun/cool like a game or something, the knowledge I have is pretty decent java / android, but I would still call my self a beginner, I aquired my knowledge from 200 'newboston' videos and other material from the internet, my HTML5/JS is on the same level as my java/android, and I feel like I dont know how to progress from here or which way to go and what tools to use, all I want is to sit down and start working on something, please recommend/help me decide the right/easy/simple way to go with the knowledge I have, or atleast point me in the direction where I can learn more.

I have found a tool called 'appMobi XDK', I consider developing with it.. and I really wanted to hear other more advanaced programmers opinions, maybe the 'xdk tool' is the wrong way to go, please help me decide and find the way to jump forward with my programming carear/skills.

I really feel lost and confused with all these tools and options around, phonegap, appmobi xdk, eclipse, html/js, unity3d...

Comment: you want to develop for desktop or mobile?

Comment: This sort of open-ended debate question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. SO is designed for specific programming questions with a definite answer (see the FAQ for more info). I've voted to close.

Comment: It is kind of open ended, but since he feels lost, we still could give him some directions. One tip from me: neither Java nor JavaScript are ideal for game development. The only measurement you have to keep your code secret is either shift the work to servers or obfuscation. Not saying it's not worth it. When developing games with JS, look up WebGL and THREE.js.

Comment: And my main goal/focus is mobile @btevfik.

Comment: @Derija93 There are other sites on the Internet that would happily address this question. The job of the moderators on this site is to prune out the questions that don't fit the FAQ.

Comment: if you want to do a web based html5 game check this site out http://www.html5gamedevelopment.com/ if you want to create a native game (let's say for iphone) than you need to work with cocos2d and objective-c some sites are : http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index and http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/. i myself haven't done any mobile game development so this is all i can help.

Comment: @DuncanJones Good point. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to make a game, what kind of game is it going to be? After you make the decision, you need to choose some engine. But the real thing to do is to sit and start doing it. What I can say is that the [appMobi XDK](http://www.appmobi.com/) is definitely the wrong way to start in this case. Even their slogan says: "Montize *existing* apps" and nothing exists in your case yet. :)

Comment: Thank you jordan! for such a quick response, I would like to start somewhere I dont really care what kind of game, even a simple tower defense game would suffice, can you point me to some direction with an engine or a way to start?

Comment: You can possibly review some of this options: http://www.andengine.org/ or http://citrusengine.com/